# Allowing Masscan To Run On More Than A Single Core

Tags: debian, cpu-usage

When I run [Masscan](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan) on my dedicated server, using Debian, I have a CPU issue. The server has 8 cores, but Masscan only uses 1 of them. In doing so, Masscan maxes out the core to 100%. I was wondering if there is anyway to distribute the process, so it has access to all of the cores? If possible, Masscan won't be demanding large amounts of resources, from 1 core, plus I'll also be able to run faster scans. Thanks, I look forward to your answers.

Comment: Do other processes seem to be able to use multiple cores? How have you come into the conclusion that `masscan` is using just one core? Please post the output of what you've done so that we have a bit more information.

Comment: Okay, I'll update the thread with more information when I get home.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `htop` and to me the (what I assume to be) CPU core loads to seem to be in conflict with the process list. I mean, you have three `masscan` processes, two of which take over 100% CPU, and still only one core is shown to be used. Also, that core is mostly taken by kernel threads. If it was something else than `masscan` I would probably  try it out myself, but I'm not willing to upsetting anyone using a tool like that which I don't know how to use without upsetting someone...

Comment: This might boil down being due to power optimisation (letting other cores idle while driving one in boost mode etc), or it might be that your network maxes out (`masscan` ought to be light on CPU anyway) and those processes are just busy waiting for network I/O. Have you checked the network stats (try `iftop` or `nethogs`)?